# save multi-select input using update_option for plugin

Tags: plugins, options

Trying to save some plugin data to the wpdb using the `update_option` method.  This code works fine for my single value `ad_url`, but fails for my array `exclude_posts`.  The POST data in Chrome dev panel shows `exclude_posts[]` getting a value of 5, but nothing is going into the wpdb.

options.php

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php
    settings_fields('insert-video-ad-settings');
    do_settings_sections('insert-video-ad-settings');
?>
    <input id=adurl type="textarea" name="ad_url" autocomplete="off" value="<?php
    echo get_option('ad_url');
    ?>"/>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['exclude_posts'])) {
     $exclude_posts = $_POST['exclude_posts'];
}

if( isset( $exclude_posts ) )
{
   update_option( 'exclude_posts', $exclude_posts );
}
else
{
   delete_option( 'exclude_posts' );
}
?>

<select id="exclude_posts" name="exclude_posts[]" multiple="multiple">
       <?php
       $postslist = get_posts(array(
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'orderby' => 'date'
       ));
       $exclude = get_option('exclude_posts');
       If(!$exclude){
          $exclude=array();
       }
  if ($postslist) {
    global $post;
    foreach ($postslist as $post)
          {
          ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php echo ( in_array( $post->ID, $exclude ) ? 'selected' : '' ); ?> >
                <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
             </option>
          <?php
          }
        }
       ?>
</select>
```

myplugin.php

```
add_action('admin_init', 'update_ad_url');

if (!function_exists("update_ad_url")) {
    function update_ad_url()
    {
        register_setting('insert-video-ad-settings', 'ad_url');
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'update_exclude_posts');

if (!function_exists("update_exclude_posts")) {
    function update_exclude_posts()
    {
        register_setting('insert-video-ad-settings', 'exclude_posts');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST['exclude_posts']` is an array but you need to store it as a string, you can always use a function like `serialize()` and `unserialize()` to turn it into a string and vice versa.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue.  Maybe I'm not really following this adapted code well.  `print_r($_POST);` always returns null, even while saving my `ad_url` data.

Comment: If POST is empty even after a form submit, it usually means that the page has been redirected.

Comment: This helped me figure it out.  Removing this code fixed it.  <?php
if(isset($_POST['exclude_posts'])) {
     $exclude_posts = $_POST['exclude_posts'];
}

if( isset( $exclude_posts ) )
{
   update_option( 'exclude_posts', $exclude_posts );
}
else
{
   delete_option( 'exclude_posts' );
}
?>